# Type alias for Array with specified dimension

Tags: arrays, types, julia

I want to have a type alias, say, `MyArrayType{N}`, so that `Array{T,N} <: MyArrayType{N}` for any `T`.
For example,

```
julia> Array{Float64, 1} <: MyArrayType{1}
true
julia> Array{Float64, 2} <: MyArrayType{1}
false
julia> Array{Float64, 2} <: MyArrayType{2}
true
julia> Array{Integer, 1} <: MyArrayType{1}
true
julia> Array{Any, 1} <: MyArrayType{1}
true
julia> Array{Any, 8964} <: MyArrayType{8964}
true
julia> Array{Any, 2047} <: MyArrayType{8964}
false
```

I know that there is already a type alias `Array{T}` which can do `Array{T,N} <: Array{T}` for any `N`. Is there already a type alias which can do what I want for the `MyArrayType` above?

Comment: Is `typealias MyArrayType Array` an acceptable answer?

Comment: I'm curious if you really need arrays with that many dimensions.  I wonder if some of the Julia code dealing with arrays might have problems with that (due to size issues with Tuples).

Comment: @Scott Jones Just an example with some funny numbers.

Comment: @user3580870 Then `MyArrayType{2}` is equivalent to `Array{2}`. It does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you note, you can always omit trailing type parameters as a short-hand for not restricting them. So by creating a typealias that swaps the order of the parameters, you can omit the array's element type:

```
julia> typealias MyArrayType{N,T} Array{T,N}
Array{T,N}

julia> Array{Float64, 1} <: MyArrayType{1}
true

julia> Array{Any, 8964} <: MyArrayType{8964}
true

julia> Array{Float64, 2} === MyArrayType{2, Float64}
true
```

Comment: Cool. I did not notice I can omit last parameters. I come across the [style guide](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/style-guide/#don-t-use-unnecessary-static-parameters). It mentions that we should avoid using unnecessary static parameters `T` if `T` is not used in the function body. Is it guideline also applicable to type alias?

Comment: Nope, type parameters in aliases are very necessary and widely used.